# how to count the number of rows with same values between 2 dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes

```
df1 <- data.frame(col11=c("a","a","a","b","b"), col=c(1,2,3,4,5))
df2 <- data.frame(col21=c("c","c","d","d","d"), col=c(1,5,1,2,5))
```

I want to count `index1` as the number of rows in `col` with the same values between 2 dataframes based to groups of `col11` of `df1` and `col21` of `df2`, and `index2` as the number of unique values in `col` of both dataframes. Then I want to take the ratio `index3` which is calculated by `index1`/`index2` for each couple of groups in `col11` and `col21`.
What I did is that I use inner and outer join tables to count `index1` and `index2` to create these intermediate dataframes

```
df3 <- data.frame(group11=c("a","a","b","b"), group21=c("c","d","c","d"), index1=c(1,2,1,1))
df4 <- data.frame(group11=c("a","a","b","b"), group21=c("c","d","c","d"), index2=c(5,6,4,5))
```

to have this resulted dataframe

```
df5 <- data.frame(group11=("a","a","b","b"), group21=c("c","d","c","d"), index3=c(0.2,0.33,0.25,0.2))
```

Could you help me to have the resulted dataframe without using join tables and without creating the intermediate dataframes? Thank you.

Comment: Could you add details on how ```index2``` is calculated? There are only 5 total numbers in ```col``` which means a result of 6 would not be possible within ```index2```. However, if it is simply the length, I follow your calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define two `Vectorize`d functions that do the job.

First we split the `col` columns of both data frames according to their `col**` and put them into a list.

```
L <- c(split(df1$col, df1$col11), split(df2$col, df2$col21))
```

Define `FUN3` to count the lengths of the intercepts, define `FUN4` to count the lengths of the "unique" values. (I named the functions according to your `dat3` and `dat4` interim data frames, since it's the corresponding step).

```
FUN3 <- Vectorize(function(x, y) length(intersect(x, y)))
FUN4 <- Vectorize(function(x, y) length(c(x, y)))
```

Use `outer` which comes from the outer product of matrices. We just need `[1:2, 3:4]` as subset of the result.

```
res3 <- as.vector(outer(L, L, FUN3)[1:2, 3:4])
res4 <- as.vector(outer(L, L, FUN4)[1:2, 3:4])
```

To follow the same logic and get them right, we do similar with the letters from the `col**` columns, where we use the list numbers 1 to 4.

```
nm <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.vector(outer(1:2, 3:4, paste)), " "))
nm <- apply(nm, 1:2, function(x) names(L)[as.double(x)])
```

Finally we `cbind` everything together and `setNames`.

```
setNames(cbind.data.frame(nm, res3 / res4), c("group11", "group21", "index3"))
#   group11 group21    index3
# 1       a       c 0.2000000
# 2       b       c 0.2500000
# 3       a       d 0.3333333
# 4       b       d 0.2000000
```

---

### Edit

`outer` gives the outer product of the whole matrices. Since we just compare `a, b` to `c, d` we just want a part of the resulting matrix. In this example we just want the first "quadrant" i.e. the upper right 4x4 sub-matrix which is rows `1:2` and columns `3:4`.

```
(res3 <- outer(L, L, FUN3))
#   a b c d
# a 3 0 1 2
# b 0 2 1 1
# c 1 1 2 2
# d 2 1 2 3
```

We may formulate that less hard-coded like so:

```
(rows <- which(rownames(res3) %in% unique(df1$col11)))  ## i.e. %in% c("a", "b")
# [1] 1 2
(cols <- which(colnames(res3) %in% unique(df2$col21)))  ## i.e. %in% c("c", "d")
# [1] 3 4

(res3 <- as.vector(res3[rows, cols]))
# [1] 1 1 2 1
```

`FUN4` accordingly.

For the **names** `nm` we want to subset the names of the `L` list. To correspond with the data, we need numerical `seq`uences according to the `length` (i.e. number) of `unique` strings of the relevant columns of both data frames. Since the numbers of the second one should be consecutive, we just add the number of the first data frame.

```
lg1 <- seq(length(unique(df1$col11)))
lg2 <- seq(length(unique(df2$col21))) + length(unique(df1$col11))

nm <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.vector(outer(lg1, lg2, paste)), " "))
(nm <- apply(nm, 1:2, function(x) names(L)[as.double(x)]))
#     [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "a"  "c" 
# [2,] "b"  "c" 
# [3,] "a"  "d" 
# [4,] "b"  "d"
```

Comment: could you please explain why we need only [1:2, 3:4] as subset of the result? My actual df has thounsands of rows but the res3 and res4 has only 4 rows.

Comment: @Liselotte Yes, see edit please, does this make sense?

Comment: @Liselotte Note, that I've added a section "names" to the edit.

Comment: I'm so sorry but what is `lg1` anf `lg2`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach which unfortunatly still has a lot of joining.

```r
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.frame(col11=c("a","a","a","b","b"), col=c(1,2,3,4,5))
df2 <- data.frame(col21=c("c","c","d","d","d"), col=c(1,5,1,2,5))
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

res = CJ(col11 = df1[["col11"]], col21 = df2[["col21"]], unique = TRUE)

res[, index1 := df1[df2, on = .(col)][, .N, keyby = .(col11, col21)]$N]
res[, index2 := mapply(function(x, y) length((c(df1[col11 == x, col], df2[col21 == y, col]))), col11, col21)]
res[, index3 := index1 / index2][]
#>     col11  col21 index1 index2    index3
#>    <char> <char>  <int>  <int>     <num>
#> 1:      a      c      1      5 0.2000000
#> 2:      a      d      2      6 0.3333333
#> 3:      b      c      1      4 0.2500000
#> 4:      b      d      1      5 0.2000000
```

We use `data.table`'s reference semantics to directly update the data.table within the call so we have no additional objects.

1. The `CJ(...)` is to set up all the unique combinations.
2. The `index1 := df1[df2, ...]` is join syntax followed by determining the count (.N) of each combination. Note, I believe it is safe to not join this back to `res` because the `keyby` will result in the same order as what was made in the `CJ`.
3. The `mapply(...)` call is a fancy loop where we filter for each row in the `res` for each combination. I will make changes depending on feedback on whether the `col` is unique or not.

Finally, it is worth pointing out that there is no simple solution for this. There are going to be intermediate calculation steps to prevent these calls from going too long.

Comment: for the code res[, index1 := df1[df2, on = .(col)][, .N, keyby = .(col11, col21)]$N], it keeps showing the errorError in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'col' not found. I don't know why

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error. Could you run just the join of ```df1[df2, on = .(col)]``` and see if you get an error?

Comment: Also, what version of ```data.table``` do you have?

Comment: I use version 1.12.8

Comment: Well, if you're interested in this approach, let me know about ```df[df2, on = .(col)]``` - I reinstalled data.table and still had no issues.